# Make Specific Content Within Anchor Tag Not Redirect But clickable for Javascript

Tags: html, css, url, redirect

I need to make an entire **div** redirect to a specific URL. However, within that **div** I also want to add other **div** tags that will be clickable so it can undergo changes from javascript.

> I wrapped the parent div with an anchor tag to make the whole div and its content redirect.

A simplified example:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="firstContainer">
        <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondContainer">
         <div class="secondBox">
              <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Edit:

1. onClick() does not work.

Also, I forgot to mention that I need it to work with event listeners and JQuery functions (click(), on(), ...)

2. The solution given works only if the number of elements remains the same.

E.g.:
webpage loads with the following elements:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="firstContainer">
        <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondContainer">
         <div class="secondBox">
              <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Javascript duplicates it:

```
// First Section
<a href="#">
    <div class="firstContainer">
        <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondContainer">
         <div class="secondBox">
              <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</a>

// Second Section
<a href="#">
    <div class="firstContainer">
        <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondContainer">
         <div class="secondBox">
              <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The solution given will not work with the second section, only the first section.

The second section is created with the following JQuery / Javascript code:

```
let el = `
<a href="#">
    <div class="firstContainer">
        <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondContainer">
         <div class="secondBox">
              <div class="noRedirctYesOnClickEvents"> <!-- Does not redirct but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change -->
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</a>
`;

document.append(el);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found for my case is to use `e.preventDefault()`. However, if you want to dynamically add elements you need to use event delegation.

```
$(parent).on("event", "element Selector", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
})
```

In my case I use:

```
$(document).on("click", "noRedirctYesOnClickEvents", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
})
```

For more information check [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Thank you to @mplungjan for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Here:  use OnClick=function() , this will fire a JS function when click on the object.

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: No, it still redirects when clicked! Also, I forgot to mention that it needs to work even with event listeners and JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I use preventDefault on the link and stopPropagation on the divs

```js
$(document).on("click",".redirect", function(e) { // delegate from document since you append to document
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
  console.log("a clicked");
})
$(document).on("click",".noRedirectYesOnClickEvents",function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from triggering the link
  console.log("noRedirectYesOnClickEvents clicked");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="redirect">
  <div class="firstContainer">Click here to redirect
    <div class="noRedirectYesOnClickEvents">
       Does not redirect but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondContainer">Click here to redirect
    <div class="secondBox">Click here to redirect
      <div class="noRedirectYesOnClickEvents">
         Does not redirect but can be changed by event E.g.: click, change 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This works fine, but what is a create a duplicate of the anchor tag, and all its descendants, it does not work. I understand why this happens, but I don't have a solution

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you show an example?

Comment: I have clarified it in the answer above.

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my computer. You need event delegation as you mentioned